# If statement taking up too much code, is there a way of simplifying this code?

Tags: swift

i have replaced my code with x, y, and z.
At the moment my code runs like this but i have a lot of lines to check x. is there a way of instead of using this

```
if x != y && x != z
```

using something like this instead

```
if x != y,z
```

sorry everyone I should have explained it better. Here is a piece of the updated code using contains which was very helpful thank you!

```
if contactCreation.checkAllowed(newContact.contactDetails){
    if{contactCreation.blockedCreation.contains(newContact.contactDetails){
        watchList.addAttempt(newContact.contactDetails)
    }   
}else{
    newAccount.showReasons()
}
```

I guess my question was more is there a way to check if x is y and if x is z but not if x is y + z. basically I wanted to call

```
if x != y && x != z && x != d && != e
```

without having to get x every-time in one if statement.
so something like this

```
if x != y && != z && != d && != e
```

thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you give me some context so i can think of the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly shorter version is to add an overload to the pattern matching operator (`~=`):

```
func ~=<T: Equatable>(pattern: [T], value: T) -> Bool {
    return pattern.contains(value)
}

if !([y,z] ~= x) {

}
```

If that expression looks a little unwieldy and you write it a lot, you can define your own operator:

```
infix operator !!= : ComparisonPrecedence

func !!=<T: Equatable>(lhs: T, rhs: [T]) -> Bool {
    return !rhs.contains(lhs)
}

if x !!= [y,z] {

}
```

Comment: thank you a lot! this is amazing. Yeah I was not sure what to search up for my question. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: this is awesome thanks a lot would you be able to suggest any tutorials in which I can learn more about this?

Comment: You can start with [Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60) and [Advanced Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID28) in the Swift book

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this condition using an array aggregate and `contains` method, like this:

```
if ![y, z].contains(x) {
    ...
}
```

This does not help much when `x` is a simple variable, but it lets you remove some code duplication when `x` is a complex expression.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't the condition be negated to match the original code?

Comment: this is great thank you a lot x is not a simple variable in my case its an object i'm passing through the if statement this is great!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest this with what you've shown for your code, but you could use tuples:

```
let testCase:(String,String) = ("hello","world")
if x != testCase {
    x = ("did not", "match")
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but i should have explains better,
would x not come back as false if one of these strings was true?